# Excel Formula with concatenate

Tags: excel, concatenation, excel-formula

I am trying to generate a customer number using the first three letters of the customers last name, the first name initial and middle initial, followed by the last four of their phone number. How would I do this? All I need is the formula.

```
First_Name   Middle_Initial Last_Name   Street_Address  City    State   Zip Phone
Nathaniel    E.             Conn        6196 View Ct    Lancing   TN    37770   567-273-3956
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this (assuming a table with [structured-references], fill in the actual cell names if not):

```
=LEFT([LastName] & "---", 3)
    & LEFT([FirstName] & "-", 1)
    & LEFT([MiddleInitial] & "-", 1)
    & RIGHT([PhoneNumber] & "----", 4)
```

I have used dashes ("-") to fill in any spaces where the field might be smaller than the number of characters you need from it.  You can change them to any fill character that suits you.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it depends on if each piece of data has its own column, looks like it does.

You can use the left/right functions to parse the data out of your columns.

`=CONCATENATE(RIGHT(C1,3) & LEFT(A1,1) & LEFT(B3,1) & RIGHT(H1,4))`

Answer (score -1):

I would do:

```
=MID(CELL_LAST_NAME;1;3)&MID(CELL_FIRST_NAME;1;1)&MID(CELL_MIDDLE_NAME;1;1)&MID(CELL_PHONE;LEN(CELL_PHONE)-3;4)
```